# Insert comment characters using preprocessor macro

Tags: c++

I am trying to create macro that allows me to simulate behaviour below, but this doesn't work. Is it possible to insert comment characters by macro? What is another option?

```cpp
#define model_interface(CLASS, ROOT) \
    class CLASS : public NInterface<ROOT> { \
    private: \
    CLASS(CLASS&) { } \
    // 'two slashes should be actually inserted too so another characters on same row are ignored'


model_interface(Element, ElementRoot) { // 'previous bracket should be ignored'

// members declarations here

}
```

Comment: Some compilers (at least one?) support `#define COMMENT / ## /` making a comment, but I don't know if that is what you are looking for. It's non-standard anyway, so it isn't a first choice solution.

Comment: Most macro content is not seen by humans when *invoked*, so comments aren't really useful.  In general, the compiler uses the Preprocessor to *generate new code* and that code is then processed by the compiler.  Some compilers have options to print the source code after the Preprocessing phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the syntax you want, but it's doable with a slightly *different* one - using parentheses.

This solution uses variadic macros, which is available since C+11, but some compilers supported it well before that.

```
#define model_interface(CLASS, ROOT, ...) \
    class CLASS : public NInterface<ROOT> { \
    private: \
    CLASS(CLASS&) { } \
    __VA_ARGS__ \
    }

model_interface(Element, ElementRoot,
    // members declarations here
    // the variadic part takes care of a comma, e.g.: std::array<int, 3> a;
);
```